# How to implement dimension table design when having different values for the same dimension according to specific criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

If I have a `Dimension Date table` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Dimension].[Date](
    [Date Key] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Day] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Day Suffix] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [Weekday] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Weekday English Name] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Weekday English Name Short] [char](3) NOT NULL,
    [Weekday English Name FirstLetter] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [Weekday Arabic Name] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [Weekday Arabic Name FirstLetter] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [Day Of Year] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Week Of Month] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Week Of Year] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Month] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Month English Name] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Month English Name Short] [char](3) NOT NULL,
    [Month English Name FirstLetter] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [Month Arabic Name] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [Month Arabic Name FirstLetter] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [Quarter] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Quarter Name] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [Year] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MMYYYY] [char](6) NOT NULL,
    [Month Year] [char](7) NOT NULL,
    [Is Weekend] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Is Holiday] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Holiday Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Special Day] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [First Date Of Year] [date] NULL,
    [Last Date Of Year] [date] NULL,
    [First Date Of Quater] [date] NULL,
    [Last Date Of Quater] [date] NULL,
    [First Date Of Month] [date] NULL,
    [Last Date Of Month] [date] NULL,
    [First Date Of Week] [date] NULL,
    [Last Date Of Week] [date] NULL,
    [Lineage Key] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__Date__B7A341C5SWWC2006D] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Date Key] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

---

I face the following problem:

Not all `weekends and holidays` are the same for all the organizational departments, There are default weekends(`Fri,Sat`) for example but some departments have different schedules so they have different weekend days. How to handle this situation when I have different values for the same dimension according to specific criteria? Should I create multiple versions for the same Dim? How to use Date Dim as a `conformed dimension` in an enterprise data warehouse in this case?

Comment: Why is your Dimension table denormalized? You only need a tiny fraction of those columns - the **vast majority** of the other columns can be expressed as `VIEW` column expressions.

Comment: @Dai Should I normalize my date dim?

Comment: **YES!** - why on earth would you be storing denormalized data when there's absolutely zero performance benefits - while simultaneously massively increasing the odds of storing anomalous data? (If you need to query (and index) derived columns you can use an indexed view).

Comment: @Dai I'm new to this field so I have followed the recommendations of  `Kimball data warehouse` toolkit. and  how the normalization will fix my problem, Could U explain your ideas in detailed answer please

Comment: @Dai Normalization in a data warehouse is an old theological argument we don't need to go into. What we could do here is create an create another table representing the schedule for a department, and join on that as well. But I'd love to know why some of the columns here are nullable

Comment: You assume much by only identifying holidays and weekends. Not every other date is a "work date". Natural and un-natural disasters force businesses to close. Other events do as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the Date dimension as a conformed table is adavntageous when  :

- One central location to update by ETL jobs
- Easy to implement “Single Source of Truth” because the same copy of
  data is visible across organization.
- Less data footprint due to removal of unnecessary copies of the same
  data.

In your case, you don't need all the columns so you can have the DimDate table in your database but pointing to it with a simple view to get only columns you need.
Also, you can have a bridge table between the DimDate view and the DimDepartment like below :

[image]

A logical data model may contain one or more many-to-many relationships. Physical data modelling techniques transform a many-to-many many-relationships into one-to many-relationships by adding additional tables. These are referred to as bridge tables.